# How to have two different \cref commands in the same document?

Tags: cross-referencing

**Problem:** I would like to cross-reference my Figures both with the traditional `\cref` command for the main Figures, resulting in the usual `Fig. 1`, `Fig. 2`, etc.. and another `\cref` command for Supplementary Figures, as `Supplementary Fig. 1`, `Supplementary Fig. 2`, etc.. in the same document.

Currently, I have the following piece of code to use `\cref`:

```
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
```

and I call it with the usual way `\cref{fig:figure_name})`.

**Question:** Is it possible to have both the usual `\cref` definition/call for Figures and an additional one, like `\crefsupp` for Supplementary Figures in the same document? If Yes, how?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to *number* the supplementary figures as `S1`, `S2`, etc -- and cross-reference them as "Figures S1, S2, and S3"?

Comment: Many thanks @Mico for your comment..! Actually I would need "Supplementary Figure 1", "Supplementary Figure 2", etc.., which is the format of a Journal, but I will be happy to see also as you mentioned, i.e. "Figures S1, S2, etc.." ....Maybe, I will be able to adapt it to my specific case...perhaps.. :-)